How to Dynamically Control a Variable to Maximize Another Variable in Dymola
I've been using Dymola for a while, but this is my first time working with controllers. I have a complex model of a thermal plant, and I need to control some variables. So far, I have successfully implemented some PI and PID controllers to control certain signals by imposing a constant setpoint.
However, I now have a different problem: I need to control a signal to maximize the value of another variable, rather than fixing it to a constant setpoint. I have looked into various methods to tackle this, such as using a PID controller, gradient method optimization, or the non-free RealTimeOptimization function, but I need some additional guidance.
Here's a simplified description (through a simple case) of what I need to achieve:
I need to control the variable inputVar (which can range from 0 to 1) to maximize the value of outputVar at each simulation time step. For example, if we simulate for 3600 seconds, the results should show how the optimum value of inputVar changes over time to maximize outputVar, starting from zero and potentially increasing up to 1.
I'm not sure how challenging this task is, and I would appreciate any suggestions or examples of how to implement this in Dymola. Thank you!
model TestOptControlSignal
  "Tests that represents a model complex that must be controlled with an input variable in order to maximize an output variable"

  //Simplified model
  parameter Real amplitude = 10;
  parameter Real frequency = 1e-4;
  parameter Real phase1 = 0;
  parameter Real phase2 = 3.14/2;
  Real sine_wave1;
  Real sine_wave2;

  Real inputVar "variable to be optimized during the entire simulation - values in range: [0,1]";
  Real outputVar "max output";

equation 
 sine_wave1 = amplitude * sin(2 * Modelica.Constants.pi * frequency * time + phase1);
 sine_wave2 = amplitude * sin(2 * Modelica.Constants.pi * frequency * time + phase2);

 inputVar = 1 "This is the variable that must be modified in order to maximize the outputVar in each step of the simulation";

 outputVar = sine_wave1*inputVar+sine_wave2*(1-inputVar);

  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")),experiment(
      StopTime=3600,
      Interval=1,
      __Dymola_Algorithm="Dassl"));
end TestOptControlSignal;


This will depend on the model. If the model is really simple you could probably just use gradient decent within Dymola to calculate the input. However if it is more complex you may want to do something like NMPC. NMPC is not directly supported in Dymola, however the model could be exported as an FMU used with for example https://tlk-energy.de/en/software/muscod.

Thank you @user2024223. For now, I think that using a gradient decent method might work. Could you help in this way with the simplified case that I presented? I couldn't find any example of gradient decent applied in Dymola. Any other reference is strongly welcome. Thank you in advance.

There is an extension of the Modelica language called Optimica that address this kind of problems in a user friendly way. But then you need to use other software than Dymola. Optimica is included in the deprecated JModelica, as well as in the commercial Impact, both from Modelon. You also have I think Optimica available in the free OpenModelica. The advantage with using Optimica is that you focus on what the problem is, not how it should be solved. If you need to stick to Dymola, implementing a gradient method might be worthwhile to try.

Dear @janpeter . Thank you very much for your answer. I really appreciate the relevant information you have provided. Unfortunately, indeed, we have to stick to Dymola. Would you give some hints about implementing the gradient method in the simplified case that I presented? Should I use the algorithm section, shouldn't? Thank you very much in advance.

I understand that you may need to stick to Dymola. Not sure how to implement some gradient method.
What I understand you like to have inputVar(t) as a function of time, and for each time instant bring max value to outputVar(t) right?
Since outputVar(t) is just a defined function of time and inputVar(t), I think you can solve the equation and get an analytical solution. But I also suspect this is a simplified problem setup and the real problem may contain dynamics in outputVar(t), is it so?

This https://www.claytex.com/tech-blog/how-to-solve-your-own-nonlinear-equation/ could give some idea of some ideas to how this problem may be solved, assuming that the model is simple enough.

Not really an answer I'm afraid, but too much for a comment, so:
What you are describing reminds me of MPPT (maximum power point tracking) for photovoltaic (PV) cells. Probably this would be a good starting point for searching the web as there should be numerous solutions. There is a simple, clocked/sampled version in the PhotoVoltaics library, namely the block PhotoVoltaics.Components.Blocks.MPTrackerSample. In the screenshot below, this would be the component mpTracker.

The disadvantage of this implementation is, that due to sampling (10s in the above case, 1s as default), it can slow down the overall simulation. If the system is comparably simple and should e.g. compute a full year which would be typical for a PV-system the events for sampling will potentially limit performance. If that is not an issue for your plant this could be a solution.
Also a more generic view on the topic that could help: https://de.mathworks.com/discovery/optimal-control.html
PS: If you find a good continuous solution, that would be a great extension for the PhotoVoltaics and similar libraries. So some feedback here would be nice :)
